What quantity remains fixed when the voltage changes?
Suppose I have an electric lamp that is designed to be connected to a 220 volt network.
Then I take it to a country with a 110 volt network, and connect it using an appropriate voltage converter. I would like to know which of the following is true:

The lamp will still use the same current (in amperes), which means that it will use half the power (in watts)? or --

The lamp will still use the same power (in watts), which means that it will use twice the current (in amperes)?


Additionally, will the light intensity be the same, or different?
In short: what quantity remains constant when the voltage changes - the current or the power?

The title does not match the question body. The title clearly mentions "when the voltage changes", but then you write "using an appropriate voltage converter". These two are mutually exclusive, pick one.

@pipe  I do not understand why they are not the same. Can you explain in more detail? Sorry for the naive question - I do not know much about this.

A 220 V lamp in 110 V land will need a step-up converter and traditionally this is a simple 110 V:220 V transformer.
The basic relationship between power (P), voltage (V) and current (I) is \$ P = VI \$ and for the transformer (ignoring efficiency losses) we'll get
$$ P_{out} = P_{in} $$
$$V_{out}I_{out} = V_{in}I_{in}$$
From this we can see that for the same power on a lower voltage circuit the current must increase and vice-versa.

The lamp will still use the same current (in amperes), which means that it will use half the power (in watts)? or --

Yes, because it's still running on a 220 V supply.

The lamp will still use the same power (in watts), which means that it will use twice the current (in amperes)?

The lamp will use the same current but the transformer will draw twice the current from the 110 V mains.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Power stays the same.  The factors contributing to that power are what change.
The most straightforward way to convert voltage is with a transformer.  Since they provided a center-tapped version I used it to show how you put twice as many turns on the high voltage side.  In a transformer, when you step up the voltage, you step down the current in the same proportion.  The same will be true for other kinds of converters.
